# Lock a Database Record For a User

Tags: sql-server-2014, locking

I have a application development requirement to lock a database record for a user while the user is inside the record. Then unlock it after they are done. Is there a way to do this at the database level instead of the code level? Should this be done at the database level or code level?

When I say lock I mean other will be able to view but not edit.

Comment: Is this a single row in a single table?

Comment: Can you please explain 'while the user is inside the record'?  If it means updating (making change to the record)--by design SQL Server will protect that record (by means to latch) from other users making changes.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  If you want to prevent users overwriting one-anothers' work, that automatically happens given use of the proper [isolation level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql).

Comment: I'm trying to prevent users from overwriting each others work.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122(v=sql.105).aspx) for details.  Level of concurrency is controlled by isolation level you chose in SQL server or in your connection. Unless specified or changed **Read committed** is the default isolation level when you install SQL server and do not overwrite in your transaction.

> Transactions specify an isolation level that defines the degree to
>   which one transaction must be isolated from resource or data
>   modifications made by other transactions. Isolation levels are
>   described in terms of which concurrency side effects, such as dirty
>   reads or phantom reads, are allowed.

That being said despite any isolation level you chose data modification is always protected.

> Choosing a transaction isolation level does not affect the locks that
>   are acquired to protect data modifications. A transaction always gets
>   an exclusive lock on any data it modifies and holds that lock until
>   the transaction completes, regardless of the isolation level set for
>   that transaction. For read operations, transaction isolation levels
>   primarily define the level of protection from the effects of
>   modifications made by other transactions.

You can still encounter lost updates if you not at least at **Repeatable read** isolation level.  See this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190805(v=sql.105).aspx) for details about repeatable read.

This is a good [article](http://www.besttechtools.com/articles/article/sql-server-isolation-levels-by-example) explaining isolation level with examples.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't give much detail on 'how long the user might be inside the record'.

Extended database locking scenarios can play havoc with the ability of the transaction log to 'clear' on a timely basis and certain isolation levels '*can*' introduce unintended consequences, like allowing others to read the 'before-data' and not being informed that data changes are 'in-flight'.

If a user can basically bring a tent and sleeping bag to 'camp-out' in this record for numerous seconds, minutes, go home, go on vacation, etc., I would strongly suggest implementing this '*locking*' in code.

At my company (insurance), we employ the use of a generic 'RESOURCE_LOCK' table that basically allows us to 'document' that a 'resource' (Policy, Claim, Bill, File, etc.) is '*locked* or *checked-out*'.  We have a STATUS column indicating things like WIP (Work-in-Progress) meaning work is actively being done, but not in a single 'database transaction' and WNIP (Work-not-in-Progress) meaning the resource is still locked but a user is not 'actively' working on it.  We also capture the UserId of the 'locking-user' and the Timestamp when the '*lock*' was acquired.  Our applications are written in such a way as to interrogate this 'RESOURCE_LOCK' table and inform others the 'status' of the 'resource'.  That allows us to ensure that only one user can be working on the 'resource' as a given time and also informs others ('readers') that data changes are '*in-flight*'.

Naturally, this does nothing to prevent a rogue TSQL statement (outside of the application and with proper authority) from updating the information that is 'locked', but that is a risk we accept.

Ultimately, you will need to decide the best course of action for your particular situation.